# Solr HTTP error: Unauthorized (401)

Tags: solr, solarium

I have an application and I've used Solarium for Solr. I have the configuration file:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return array(
        'adapteroptions' => array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 8983,
            'path' => '/solr/',
        ));
}
```

and it worked just fine. The problem I have now is that I've moved the application into another server and it seem that the port is changed. This are the dates I receive:

```
tomcat7 installed and solr 4.7.2. 
You cand check at www.mysite:8080/solr
user: mysiteuser password:mysitepass
```

So in my config file I've changed the port in 8080, but I get the following error:

```
Solr HTTP error: Unauthorized (401)
```

Can someone help me to write the correct settings? How can I set the user and password?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define it via the specific endpoint:

```
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);
$client->getEndpoint()->setAuthentication(SOLR_SERVER_USERNAME, SOLR_SERVER_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: This is best solution because the one above won't work with "@"... which was my case. Thanks.